# Selecting a property when screen is of purticular size

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
    color: red;
}

div[class$=md] {
    color: blue;
}

div[class$=sm] {
    color: green;
}
```

I am using CSS to change the colour of content of div whenever the screen size changes. But I'm am not getting expected output with above code.

Answer (score 0):

You user media query. Ex [click](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_mediaquery)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Resize the browser window. When the width of this document is 600 pixels or less, the background-color is "lightblue", otherwise it is "lightgreen".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: won't I be able to solve it using bootstrap screen width variables.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any idea about that.

Comment: It's okay.I/we will find it.